# How to implement an override method of implemented interfaces with the same signature in java. And give different implementations for each interface

Tags: java, interface, multiple-inheritance

Let's say I have two interfaces InterfaceA and InterfaceB with the same method signature.
InterfaceA:

```
public interface InterfaceA {
    void printInterfaceName();
}
```

And InterfaceB:

```
public interface InterfaceB {
    void printInterfaceName();
}
```

And I have a Printing class that is implementing both the interface
Printing class:

```
public class Printing implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
    // want to override the printInterfaceName() method such way
    // so that it will give an output which given in main method comment
}
```

And I have a Main class with a main method on it

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InterfaceA a = new Printing();
        InterfaceB b = new Printing();

        a.printInterfaceName(); // this is should print `INTERFACE-A`
        b.printInterfaceName(); // and this is should print `INTERFACE-B`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the method is not aware of the context (a.printInterfaceName() or b.printInterfaceName()), it will not be possible to distinguish between both of them and print *INTERFACE-A* or *INTERFACE-B*.

As far as I know, neither reflection nor instanceof can do the trick. Having default Methods in the Interfaces wont work either.

Maybe you can write more about your intention, so that a different solution can be suggested?

Comment: This was by an interviewer in my recent interview for java developer